# How to store React local state to Redux global store (HOOKS)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, socket.io

```
const initReactiveProperties = (user: any) => {
    //TODO: change 'any' to customized interface
    user.connected = true;
    user.messages = [];
    user.hasNewMessages = false;
    setConnectedUsersList((prevUsers: any) => [...prevUsers, user]); //setting the connected users in state
  };

  // storing connected users
  const setConnectedUsers = () => {
    socket.on("users", (users) => {
      users.forEach((user: any) => {
        user.self = user.userID === socket.id; // if the user is the authenticated user
        initReactiveProperties(user);
      });
      users = users.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a.self) return -1;
        if (b.self) return 1;
        if (a.username < b.username) return -1;
        return a.username > b.username ? 1 : 0;
      });
    });
  };

  // after new user connects, store it in an array
  const storeNewUser = () => {
    socket.on("user connected", (user) => {
      initReactiveProperties(user);
      // dispatch({ type: CONNECTED_USERS, payload: connectedUsersList });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setConnectedUsers();
    storeNewUser();
    dispatch({ type: CONNECTED_USERS, payload: connectedUsersList });
  }, []);
```

connectedUsersList gets all the currently connected users, I want to update usersList which is in my redux global store, but it does not get store in redux state immediately as connectedUsersList. But it does not.

Comment: Could you elaborate your requirement, as to why do you want it to be updated immediately?

Comment: I want to store my connectedUsersList which is in my local state to usersList which is in my global store redux

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do something after redux is updated with new connectedUsersList, you can make use of useEffect.

```
const usersListFromRedux = useSelector(state => state.usersReducer.usersList)

useEffect(() => {
  ...do something
}, [usersListFromRedux]);
```